# 2014 Nissan Sentra FE-S Alignment issues

Tags: tires, nissan, alignment, sentra, wheel-balance

I just bought a 2014 Nissan Sentra with low miles 33k.  I noticed that the tires had been replaced at 25k which seemed low to me.  I received the service report on the car after buying it and it shows that the alignment is off on the cross camber/castor?  I can hear some knocking when I make a sharp turn to the right.  Also smelling burning when I am braking down hill.  Doing some research on this and I'm reading that shims may help with proper alignment? I don't want to be driving an unsafe car. In rain the tires kind of slide when stepping on gas pedal.  Any help would be appreciated.  Here is the alignment report.  Thank you!!
[image]

Comment: Too much power on wet roads gets most tires to slide - trick is two-fold: one apply less power or two, be capable of controlling the slide.

Comment: How is the Cross Camber/Caster off? Both are between the specified ranges.

Comment: The front toe errors would scrub a bit of rubber off the tires, but there is nothing on that report that is relevant to your knocking noises and burning smells.  "In rain the tires kind of slide when stepping on gas pedal." - when did you last check the tire pressures? But every car "torque steers" to some extent.

Comment: There are a lot of questions here - seems like you'd benefit from focusing on one. As an aside I replace my tyres between 8k and 10k miles. 25k seems astonishingly high to me...